# Extend NHibernate DriverConnectionProvider class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, nhibernate

I'm working on an old web app. It has extended the `DriverConnectionProvider` of NHibernate to issue a db connection. Following is the code.

```
public class NewConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
   public override System.Data.IDbConnection GetConnection()
   {
        IDbConnection conn = base.GetConnection();       
        //execute a SP here.. to set up proxy user to connect to
        //oracle db
       return conn;
   }

}

 //connection string
<add name="connname" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = 
(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = .....)(PORT = ....)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ....)));Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=500;Proxy User Id=....; 
 Proxy Password=.....;Validate Connection=True;Connection Timeout=100;" />
```

**Question:** The problem we are having is that # of connections are spiked up to the `Max Pool Size` of the connection string. Sometimes we get connection time out error. How does the connection pooling works in this case? Do I need to override the `DriverConnectionProvider.CloseConnection` as well? If yes when do I need to call it? The system is using NHibernate,Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that the connection is never closed. You probably need to implement,

```
public void CloseConnection(IDbConnection connection)
```

in your ConnectionProvider. [Read more](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/09/18/extending-nhibernate-s-driverconnectionprovider.html)